# setup vsftp and upload file

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I am trying to setup an anonymous ftp server on Ubuntu. I installed `vsftpd` with upload directory /srv/ftp the following lines to `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
local_root=/srv/ftp
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_world_readable_only=NO
seccomp_sandbox=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

Unfortunately when I ftp in then and try to put a file I get a '553 Could not create file'. I read that the issue could be with rights on the upload dir so I added `ftp` user to the directory and writing rights using `chown` and `chmod`:

```
sudo chown ftp:ftp /srv/ftp
sudo chmod 777 /srv/ftp
```

However, then I can't ftp in anymore and I get `500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()`. I also added the flag `allow_writeable_chroot` to the config file which did not help.

When I do chmod 2775 I can login but everytime I put something I get a 553.

I tested this with locally as well with 'ftp localhost'

Thanks for any help

Comment: How about 2775 for permissions? `sudo chmod 2775 /srv/ftp -R`?

Comment: I hope the server is not publicly accessible (*i.e.*, not connected to the Internet). If it is, you *will* get questionable content uploaded on it.

Comment: Also, please paste your entire config file.